# Shared and non-shared history together

Tags: zsh, tmux, command-history

Using `zsh` (in `tmux`), I would like to access the session history with <kbd>Up</kbd>, and the shared history with <kbd>Shift+Up</kbd> (or similar).

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your terminal outputs <kbd>Up</kbd> as `^[[A`:

```
up-line-or-history() {
  zle .set-local-history -n ${#WIDGET:#*global*}  # 0 iff $WIDGET == *global*
  zle .up-line-or-history
}
zle -N up-line-or-history-local up-line-or-history
zle -N up-line-or-history-global up-line-or-history

# Up arrow
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-history-local

# Alt + up arrow
bindkey '^[^[[A' up-line-or-history-global
```

To check what your terminal actually outputs when you press <kbd>Up</kbd>, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Up</kbd>.

For more info on how the code above works, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html