# Making the "r" built-in in zsh only consider local history in a shared history situation

Tags: zsh, command-history

The `r` built-in utility in the `zsh` shell, if used with no options, re-executes the most recent command in the command history.

The issue with this is that if you have a number of shell sessions sharing history (the `SHARE_HISTORY` shell option is set), it's fairly easy to make the mistake of executing commands from a "non-local" shell session without intending to do so. This makes using `r` potentially dangerous.

**Question:** How may one either change the behavior of `r` to only consider history events local to the current shell session, or write a separate alias or function, `rl`, that only considers local events?

Since `r` is supposed to be the same as `fc -e -` (recall the most recent command, don't edit it, then execute it), I thought maybe using `r -L` or `fc -e - -L` would do it, but for whatever reason, it only seems to work if the most recent *global* history event is from the current shell session. If this is not the case, the shell complains with an `fc: no matching events found` error.

`zsh` version 5.8 (`zsh-5.8-0-g77d203f`) is in use here, from the `zsh-5.8p0` package on OpenBSD 6.8.

Tangentially related question:

- [Shared and non-shared history together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481646/shared-and-non-shared-history-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `r -L` was not working as expected was recognized as a bug when I asked about it on the `zsh-users` mailing list.

[The bug was corrected](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/6bef719302d6db33c63fb6f2636986dff1941ac2/tree/Src/builtin.c?diff=9c0533931c51b7d512d3e95850404f5aac2dbce1) on the 18th of February 2021, on the shell's Git development branch:

```
commit 6bef719302d6db33c63fb6f2636986dff1941ac2
Author: Peter Stephenson <retracted>
Date:   Thu Feb 18 21:37:08 2021 +0000

    users/26509: fix for r -L

    fc with the -L option should ignore remote entires, rather than
    reading them and treating them as an error.
```