# Define hierarchy of history files for ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

My zsh syncs history across terminals. Sometimes this is useful. But many times I just need the last command ran on a specific terminal.  
So I'd like to have two history files in use by each terminal - one that is global, and one that is per terminal. I'd like the one per terminal to have priority, and if auto-complete can't find a command there, it should search the global history. 
I think it'll be easy to write history to two files, but Im not sure how to get zsh to look at two files in the same time.

I know that I can define a keyboard shortcut that switches history files, but that's not exactly what I want either.

I would also be happy to hear of a solution to bash (rather than zsh), as it might help me find a workaround.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you specify concretely and step by step exactly how you want the searching and writing of history to work? It’s hard to answer your question without knowing exactly what behavior you’re looking for.

Comment: The `r` built-in in `zsh` should re-run the most recent command from the history. The utility can take a `-L` option to re-run the most recent "local" command (i.e., from _this_ session). Is that what you're looking for? Note that until recently, [this was not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631799/making-the-r-built-in-in-zsh-only-consider-local-history-in-a-shared-history-s/636845#636845).